# Google Chrome Extension : delete cookie in background script

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, the user logs in via the main page and that sets a cookie via the server response. This cookie is accessible to the background script which requests more data from the server.
All of this is working fine. The problem is only when you want to log the user out. When the user logs out, I can delete the cookie from the main page but the background script somehow still has a cached value of the cookie and hence the user is actually not logged out. How do I delete cookie in the background script? Here's the code that I use to delete the cookie :

```
//works on main page does not work on the background script javascript
document.cookie = "ring-session=";
```

For the record, I have also tried :

```
document.cookie = 'ring-session=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

and

```
$.removeCookie("ring-session");//using jquery.cookie.js extension
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Need to use the chrome.cookies api : http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html#method-remove

```
  chrome.cookies.remove({name:"ring-session", url:"http://127.0.0.1"},function(){
    console.log("ring-session successfully deleted!");
  });
```